# User directory - framework

Tags: api, frameworks

I'ld like to create a very basic directory where user can enter their social network profiles and pick a username. From that data a little website gets generated.
The sign in process should be managed via Twitter or Facebook.

Where do I start with this? Are there any frameworks, api's or something like that available?

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 2):

Each Social Network has its Own API.. Start there.

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554648/FrontPage

http://developers.facebook.com/

Twitter Single Sign on:
http://dev.twitter.com/pages/sign_in_with_twitter

And lastly.. the blog post that got me started with my first twitter app:
http://www.snipe.net/2009/07/writing-your-first-twitter-application-with-oauth/